# Question about $\leq$ and $\geq$ symbols in proofs

Tags: logic

If I discover that a particular proposition is valid for $a \gt b$, I can then conclude that the proposition is also valid for $a\geq b$.

However, let's say that I also know that the proposition is *not valid* for $a=b$. Is it "good practice" to press onward in a proof with the claim that the proposition is valid for $a \geq b$?

I understand that "logically" it is okay...but it seems that one is sort of *omitting known information* if he/she proceeds with the statement $a \geq b$ instead of $a \gt b$.

Comment: I feel that this is contextual. Speaking in the general, it's neither good practice nor bad practice. If it is crucial to the proof, you could say that a is *strictly* greater than b, or instead use interval notation. If it's not crucial, then it's arbitrary.

Comment: I recall asking a question about this years ago, and was told that it doesn't matter which way it's done. I have studied textbooks where the author simply used what was "logically valid", as you say, rather than what you imply is "good practice". I think of the former situation as a "weak condition", and the latter as a "strong condition". It confused me too, because it seems superfluous, albeit, logically valid. Personally, I do not understand why someone would phrase the condition in its "weak" form, since, as I said, it's just superfluous and lends itself to confusion.

Comment: Are the quantifiers clear here?  It is certainly true that the theorem "$\exists a>b\,|\,P(a,b)$" implies the theorem "$\exists a≥b\,|\,P(a,b)$" .  Is that what you are asking?  If you change the quantifier to "$\forall$" then the first result does not imply the second.  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @lulu perfect! Very helpful. I assume the reason that the $\forall$ quantifier changes the validity of the implication is because that would include $a=b$, correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly,  With that in mind (and sticking with $\exists$) the first theorem is stronger than the second, so if it is true it would be better practice to phrase the result that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is true that $a >b$ then clearly it is true that $a \geq b$

However, when you say that

> If I discover that a particular proposition is valid for $a \gt b$, I can then conclude that the proposition is also valid for $a\geq b$.

that is actually *not* the case. For example, just because some proposition is true for all numbers greater than $0$ doesn't mean that it is true for all numbers greater or equal to $0$.

Logically, we can analyze this as follows:

Saying that something is true for all numbers $a>b$ would be:

$\forall a (a >b \to P(a))$

where $P(a)$ is the proposition you make for $a$.

Saying that something is true for all $a \geq b$ would be:

$\forall a (a \geq b \to P(a))$

Now, we see that the antecedent $a \geq b$ of the conditional of this second expression is *weaker* than the antecedent $a >b$ of the first expression. (Again, this is because $a \geq b$ follows from $a >b$. ) As such, we can say that going from the first to the second statement we have Weakened the Antecedent.

However, it turns out that Weakening the Antecedent is an invalid inference. In fact, Sterengthening the Antecedent *is* valid. So, you *can* infer the first from the second.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the jargon...when you use the adjective "weaker", is that referring to the number of elements that are being referenced? i.e. $\forall a (a \geq b ...)$ actually references more elements than $\forall a (a \gt b ...)$ and hence it is weaker (it references one more element, specifically)? If not, what exactly does "weaker" mean?

Comment: @S.Cramer A statement $X$ is 'weaker' than a statement $Y$ iff statement $X$ is logically implied by statement $Y$, i.e.: statement $X$ follows from statement $Y$, i.e. statement $X$ is true if statement $Y$ is true. So, this is a very general notion that involves claims ... and those claims need not be about numbers. Here is an example: compare 'I am rich and happy' with 'I am happy'. Clearly, the latter statement is a 'weaker' statement: it doesn't 'claim as much' as the former. And indeed, if the former is true, then the latter is true .. but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

YES.

$a \ge b$ means: $a > b \lor a=b$ and the [inference $\dfrac {P}{P \lor Q}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction) is valid.

Alternatively: $a \ge b$ is $\lnot (a < b)$ and thus, using [trichotomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_(mathematics)): $a > b \lor a=b$.

Comment: oh, interesting. I was always under the impression that $a\geq b$ employed the "exclusive or"...because how can something be both greater than $b$ and equal to $b$. Why is this so?

Comment: @S.Cramer If two things are already mutually exclusive, then regardless of whether we use exclusive or or regular or between them, we get the same result in the end. So it technically doesn't matter which one we use to define $a\geq b$. However, exclusive or is much less common in mathematics in general, so regular or is preferred for that reason.